Why is flutter giving me this error and how do i fix it?
Good Morning, I was working on this template and I have come to a problem. I can't find any solutions online to fix the problem. I am getting an error at URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(selectedUrl!)).
Error is saying that `it is The argument type 'Uri' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'WebUri?'. How do I fix the error?

Error: the argument type 'Uri' can't be assigned to the parameter type
'WebUri?'.

await browser?.openUrlRequest(
      urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(selectedUrl!)),
      options: InAppBrowserClassOptions(
        crossPlatform:
            InAppBrowserOptions(hideUrlBar: true, hideToolbarTop: true),
        inAppWebViewGroupOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true, useOnLoadResource: true),
        ),
      ),
    );


I think you are using flutter InAppWebView package, which using WebUri instead of Uri.
Just use it like this way:
URLRequest(url: WebUri(selectedUrl!))

Full code:
await browser?.openUrlRequest(
      urlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri(selectedUrl!)),
      options: InAppBrowserClassOptions(
        crossPlatform:
            InAppBrowserOptions(hideUrlBar: true, hideToolbarTop: true),
        inAppWebViewGroupOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
              useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true, useOnLoadResource: true),
        ),
      ),
    );

Official docs:
inappwebview.dev/docs/web-uri
